# How does FTP handle endianess between Power and Intel systems?

Tags: ftp, endianness

When writing procedures using FTP operations, one has the option of sending the information in either Binary mode or ASCII mode.  When sending from a Power system to an Intell system, ASCII handles how the data is supposed to be represented, not bit by bit.  **However, I am curious to know how does FTP handle endianess (where Intel uses little endian and Power Systems use big Endian) between hosts?**

When opening a text file transfered in binary, it appears that the much of the ASCII representation is presevered with the exception of missing carraige return control characters that Microsoft uses to print a new line in a text document.  With that being said, it would appear that most FTP API's handle the endianess correction between hosts.  **But with that said, is it truly a bit for bit tansfer or byte for byte transfer?  Is the FTP API or the OS handling the the conversion?**

Comment: There is no endianness when you are just transferring streams of bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endianness describes how computers combine bytes to form multi-byte values (eg, a 4-byte integer).

FTP deals with individual bytes, not multi-byte values.
Endianness is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Seems the term "Binary Mode" is a little missleading.  Thanks for the answering.

Comment: @hydroparadise: "Binary Mode" means transferring raw bytes, without treating them as ASCII characters and converting newlines.

Comment: When I think Binary, I'm thinking raw bits, not bytes. Confuses people like me who do not have firm foundation in computer science, thus posting question that get down voted from ignorance. :P

Comment: @hydroparadise: Binary _is_ raw bits.  Endianness is _not_ raw bits; it's how _bytes_ are combined to form words and dwords.  FTP doesn't use words or dwords.

Comment: That clears alot of things up for me.  Thanks for taking the time :D